# Function sequence error in Hive using date sub or date add functions

Tags: hive, hiveql, business-objects

I am trying to perform a date sub function using Hive on Business objects but whenever i run it it says function sequence error and I am not sure what modificaions i can do for it to work.

The command i am using is `Hive_date=date_sub(current_date(), 1)` or `Hive_date=date_sub(current_date,1)`. I have also tried the same with `date_add` with -1 as the integer. When i run a syntax check it works but when i bring it to my report where  `effective_date=Hive_date` in throws a
`[Microsoft]{ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but you can't do an assignment like `x=function(y)` in Hive SQL. you can do a `SELECT date_sub(current_date(), 1) as Hive_date;` for example, but not what you're trying.

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit confusing but when i say example_date=current_date() it works but when i say example_date=date_add(current_date(),-1) it doesn't work. It also doesnt work with example_date=date_sub(current_date(),1)